# geoJSON formatting needs to be nested more deeply

Tags: json, formatting, polygon, geojson

I'm have an exported `geoJSON` format containing a long series of polygon coordinates. Attaching the first few rows, it continues in the same way:

```
{
  "Type": 8,
  "Features": [
    {
      "Type": 7,
      "Id": null,
      "Geometry": {
        "Type": 4,
        "Coordinates": [
          {
            "Type": 2,
            "Coordinates": [
              {
                "Altitude": null,
                "Latitude": 85.683948266763423,
                "Longitude": 100.62897140939768
              },
              {
                "Altitude": null,
                "Latitude": 86.183185093020128,
                "Longitude": 100.62897140939695
              },
              {
                "Altitude": null,
                "Latitude": 86.183185093020128,
                "Longitude": 102.58500571589823
              },
              {
                "Altitude": null,
                "Latitude": 97.662303996119974,
                "Longitude": 102.58500571589828
              },
              {
                "Altitude": null,
                "Latitude": 97.662303996119988,
                "Longitude": 97.853903401585853
              },
              {
                "Altitude": null,
                "Latitude": 85.683948266763423,
                "Longitude": 97.853903401585839
              },
              {
                "Altitude": null,
                "Latitude": 85.683948266763423,
                "Longitude": 100.62897140939768
              }
            ],
            "BoundingBoxes": null,
            "CRS": null
          }
        ],
        "BoundingBoxes": null,
        "CRS": null
      },
      "Properties": {
        "Name": "Shop",
        "Area": 572.15969696515185
      },
      "BoundingBoxes": null,
      "CRS": null
    },
    {
      "Type": 7,
      "Id": null,
      "Geometry": {
        "Type": 4,
        "Coordinates": [
          {
            "Type": 2,
            "Coordinates": [
              {
                "Altitude": null,
                "Latitude": 91.298364266763443,
                "Longitude": 86.631773715898134
              },
              {
```

I tried looking at various explanations of the `geoJSON` format online, but haven't found info about why the `"Type"` is numeric and not matching the actual type such as `"Polygon"`.

In addition, while testing on [GeoJSON Viewer & Validator](https://geojsonlint.com/), I tried debugging and converted some of the initial lines to:

```
{
  "type": "MultiPolygon",
  "coordinates": [
    {
      "type": 7,
      "Id": null,
      "Geometry": {
        "Type": "Polygon",
        "Coordinates": [
          {
            "Type": 2,
            "Coordinates": [
              {
                "Altitude": null,
                "Latitude": 85.683948266763423,
                "Longitude": 100.62897140939768
              },
```

I replaced `Type` with `type` and `8` with `MultiPolygon` etc.
With the above situation in place, I get the following error for each Polygon:

> Line 5: a number was found where a coordinate array should have been
> found: this needs to be nested more deeply

I'm not sure what to change in the format in order to make it coherent for the validator. I think the export format might be old but I'm not the one that built it so perhaps a manual replacement of some fields can solve the issue.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but it seems like it's not valid GeoJSON, you can find the official JSON schemas that describe the specification here:
https://github.com/geojson/schema.
It is for instance specified that `type` of a feature should be a JSON object and not an integer, that for each feature, `type`, `properties` and `geometry` are required, etc.

```
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "https://geojson.org/schema/Feature.json",
  "title": "GeoJSON Feature",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "type",
    "properties",
    "geometry"
  ]
(etc.)
```

For a MultiPolygon here is the schema : https://geojson.org/schema/MultiPolygon.json

The way that coordinates are stored in your file aren't standard GeoJSON either, as they should be written as array of numbers:

```
"coordinates": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "array",
          "minItems": 4,
          "items": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 2,
            "items": {
              "type": "number"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```